# Activity hight is not covered when running on small size screens

Tags: android

So i am working App and it seems working fine. But when I run small screen size device(only 5.5 inches and below screen sizes) like Samsung galaxy or nexus 4,  the layout height is not covering fully on the screen however layout width is adjusting though.

Here is my XML file:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#de0c101e"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    tools:context="com.newleaf.calculator.MainActivity">


    <EditText
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:minHeight="101dp"
        android:textSize="86sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
        android:textColor="#deffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:id="@+id/txtScreen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/btnClear"
            android:minHeight="88dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:text="AC"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
            android:textColor="#de0c101e"
            android:textSize="36sp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="88dp"
            android:id="@+id/plusminus"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:text="+/-"
            android:textColor="#de0c101e"
            android:textSize="36sp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="88dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="%"
            android:id="@+id/modul"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:textColor="#de0c101e"
            android:textSize="36sp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="88dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="/"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:id="@+id/btnDivide"
            android:background="@drawable/orenge"
            android:textColor="#deffffff"
            android:textSize="36sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:text="7"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:minHeight="88dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnSeven"
            android:textColor="#de0c101e"
            android:textSize="36sp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:id="@+id/btnEight"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:text="8"
            android:minHeight="88dp"
            android:textColor="#de0c101e"
            android:textSize="36sp"/>
        <Button
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="88dp"
            android:text="9"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnNine"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:textColor="#de0c101e"
            android:textSize="36sp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="*"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:minHeight="88dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnMultiply"
            android:background="@drawable/orenge"
            android:textColor="#deffffff"
            android:textSize="36sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:id="@+id/btnFour"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:text="4"
            android:minHeight="88dp"
            android:textColor="#de0c101e"
            android:textSize="36sp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:minHeight="88dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnFive"
            android:textColor="#de0c101e"
            android:textSize="36sp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="88dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="6"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnSix"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:textColor="#de0c101e"
            android:textSize="36sp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="-"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:minHeight="88dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnSubtract"
            android:background="@drawable/orenge"
            android:textColor="#deffffff"
            android:textSize="36sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="88dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnOne"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:text="1"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:textColor="#de0c101e"
            android:textSize="36sp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:text="2"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:minHeight="88dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:textColor="#de0c101e"
            android:textSize="36sp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="3"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnThree"
            android:minHeight="88dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:textColor="#de0c101e"
            android:textSize="36sp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="88dp"
            android:text="+"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:background="@drawable/orenge"
            android:textColor="#deffffff"
            android:textSize="36sp"/>


    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp">
        <Button
            android:minHeight="88dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:text="0"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:id="@+id/btnZero"
            android:textColor="#de0c101e"
            android:textSize="36sp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:minHeight="88dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="."
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnDot"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:textColor="#de0c101e"
            android:textSize="36sp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:minHeight="88dp"
            android:text="="
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:id="@+id/btnEqual"
            android:background="@drawable/orenge"
            android:textColor="#deffffff"
            android:textSize="36sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

i think the `minHeight` is coursing problem.its not adjusting as different screen sizes?I know there is way to fix by adding different layout on every device screen. I don't want to do that. Is there any way to overcome `minHeight` issue on small screen sizes?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: I posted the XML file alreday

Comment: *A screenshot of layout discrepancy.

Comment: Use the *dimen values*.

Comment: @FajarKhan check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use layout `weights` to fit it on any device check the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#de0c101e"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:weightSum="10">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtScreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
        android:minHeight="101dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#deffffff"
        android:textSize="86sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnClear"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:minHeight="88dp"
                android:text="AC"
                android:textColor="#de0c101e"
                android:textSize="36sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/plusminus"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:minHeight="88dp"
                android:text="+/-"
                android:textColor="#de0c101e"
                android:textSize="36sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/modul"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:minHeight="88dp"
                android:text="%"
                android:textColor="#de0c101e"
                android:textSize="36sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnDivide"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:minHeight="88dp"
                android:text="/"
                android:textColor="#deffffff"
                android:textSize="36sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSeven"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:minHeight="88dp"
                android:text="7"
                android:textColor="#de0c101e"
                android:textSize="36sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnEight"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:minHeight="88dp"
                android:text="8"
                android:textColor="#de0c101e"
                android:textSize="36sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnNine"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:minHeight="88dp"
                android:text="9"
                android:textColor="#de0c101e"
                android:textSize="36sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnMultiply"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:minHeight="88dp"
                android:text="*"
                android:textColor="#deffffff"
                android:textSize="36sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnFour"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:minHeight="88dp"
                android:text="4"
                android:textColor="#de0c101e"
                android:textSize="36sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnFive"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:minHeight="88dp"
                android:text="5"
                android:textColor="#de0c101e"
                android:textSize="36sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSix"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:minHeight="88dp"
                android:text="6"
                android:textColor="#de0c101e"
                android:textSize="36sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSubtract"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:minHeight="88dp"
                android:text="-"
                android:textColor="#deffffff"
                android:textSize="36sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnOne"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:minHeight="88dp"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#de0c101e"
                android:textSize="36sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:minHeight="88dp"
                android:text="2"
                android:textColor="#de0c101e"
                android:textSize="36sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnThree"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:minHeight="88dp"
                android:text="3"
                android:textColor="#de0c101e"
                android:textSize="36sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:minHeight="88dp"
                android:text="+"
                android:textColor="#deffffff"
                android:textSize="36sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnZero"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:minHeight="88dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#de0c101e"
                android:textSize="36sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnDot"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:minHeight="88dp"
                android:text="."
                android:textColor="#de0c101e"
                android:textSize="36sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnEqual"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:minHeight="88dp"
                android:text="="
                android:textColor="#deffffff"
                android:textSize="36sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Fajar khan you dont want these space?

Comment: Yeah i dont want those space how ever for smaller screens there is no space in between layout it works fine! Thank you

Comment: @FajarKhan if i help you in any way please tick mark and vote up happy coding :)

Comment: Yeah tysm. Please edit your answer with only updated section so i can accept :)

Comment: @FajarKhan Edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
            <EditText
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="86sp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
    android:textColor="#deffffff"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:id="@+id/txtScreen"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/height" />


     in values(change height and width vaules depending on screensize) folder put this
      <dimen name="width">100dp</dimen>
     <dimen name="hight">40dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add your layout in `scrollview` field.

```
<ScrollView >
       ....
       ....
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: no I don't want add scrollview i just want fit height to small screen sizes